# does EMR cluster size matters to read data from S3 using spark

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-s3-select

Setup:  latest (5.29) AWS EMR, spark, 1 master 1 node.

step 1.  I have used S3Select to parse a file & collect all file keys for pulling from S3.
step 2.  Use pyspark iterate the keys in a loop and do the following

spark
  .read
  .format("s3selectCSV")
  .load(key)
  .limit(superhighvalue)
  .show(superhighvalue)

It took be x number of minutes.

When I increase the cluster to 1 master and 6 nodes, I am not seeing difference in time.  It appears to me that I am not using the increased core nodes.
Everything else, config wise are defaults out of the box, I am not setting anything.

So, my question is does cluster size matters to read and inspect (say log or print) data from S3 using EMR, Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, size does matter.  For my use case, `sc.parallelize(s3fileKeysList)`, **parallelize** turned out to be the key.

Answer (score 0):

Few thing to keep in mind.

1. are you sure that the executors have indeed increased because of
   increase of nodes? or u can specify them during spark submit
   `--num-executors 6`. MOre nodes doenst mean nore executors are spinned.
2. next thing, wht is the size of csv file? some 1MB? then u will not see much difference. Make sure to have atleast 3-4 GB

Comment: Yes, I did play with **--num-executors** option with my **spark-submit** command.  It was 1 (when core was 1) and it did update to 4 when I created a new cluster with number of cores >1. <br/>  csv files range fom 2MB to 100MB.

Comment: I tried the following and I think my code is not taking advantage of spark parallelization.  Can we do this?  I tired it, it finishes fast, however, when I try to load and show it does not display anything to spark log.     <br/> `//s3fileKeysList lets say a list of s3 file keys are in this variable
sc=sparkSession.SparkContext
fileKeyListParallelized=sc.parallelize(s3fileKeysList)
allData=fileKeyListParallelized.map (lambda file:
spark
  .read
  .format("s3selectCSV") 
  .load("s3://path/to/my/"+file)
)`

Comment: can u try this: `val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("s3a://bucket/prefix/foldername/")` https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: I am not using databricks.  Anyhow, I could conclude that generally speaking cluster size does matter for reading from S3.  While debugging this further the key for me was **parallelize**.  I could see the time went down.